# data-value attribute in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I want to add data-value attribute in input element:

```
{{input type="text" data-value=ec.ec_id  value=ec.ecl_subject placeholder=ec.ecl_en_subject name="ecl_subject"  class="form-control" }}
```

But its not visible in browser:

```
<input id="ember874" class="ember-view ember-text-field form-control" placeholder="Doctor4US: Appointment" type="text" name="ecl_subject">
```

Comment: Ember not allowed unknown attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ADDING DATA ATTRIBUTES**

By default, view helpers do not accept data attributes

i.e.

```
{{input type="text" data-value=ec.ec_id  value=ec.ecl_subject name="ecl_subject" }}
```

Render as

```
<input id="ember257" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text" value="12">
```

> There are two ways to enable support for data attributes. One way
>   would be to add an attribute binding on the view, e.g. Ember.TextField for the specific attribute:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-value']
});
```

**Now the same handlebars code above renders the following HTML:**

```
<input id="ember259" class="ember-view ember-text-field" 
       type="text" data-value="110" value="12">
```

**You can also automatically bind data attributes on the base view with the following:**

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var self = this;

    // bind attributes beginning with 'data-'
    Em.keys(this).forEach(function(key) {
      if (key.substr(0, 5) === 'data-') {
        self.get('attributeBindings').pushObject(key);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

For more detail reffer:https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Ember Input helpers doesn't allow data-attributes. The list of allowed attributes can be found at https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/input-helpers/

The solution for problem is that you use html  tag itself, when you want to place data-attributes like below

```
<input type="text" data-value="{{ec.ec_id}}" value="{{ec.ecl_subject}}" placeholder="{{ec.ecl_en_subject}}" name="ecl_subject" class="form-control/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sumit but with html input model auto binding not working.

Comment: ok the two way data binding should work but in any case if it doesn't you can also do what is suggested in https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/#toc_adding-data-attributes

Comment: Came across this github issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11224, so the only option is that you reopen the TextField component and the required data atrributes